# How can I control where smoke and fire are emitted from?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

How can I control which part of the object the fire/smoke is emitted from so instead of it coming from the corners it is emitted from the top side like a normal log on fire.

[image: Here is my work]
Also I can't see the faces of the object even though I am out of edit and wire frame mode can someone please explain that as well.

Comment: I'd try using particles! you can then set them to start going up, correcting the misdirected velocity of the fire.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assign the smoke and fire to come out of just a vertex group.

Select the vertices you want the fire and smoke to come out of, and create a vertex group and assign the vertices to it:

[image]

Then go to Smoke Flow advanced and use the vertex group to determine where the fire and smoke will come out of.

[image]

[image]

**Note**: Every time you make any changes to the smoke/fire simulation you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to update the simulation cache.

To set up the materials and actually render your smoke in cycles watch

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs

Comment: Could the texture option be used to make it so some parts are more on fire than other parts? Thanks.

Comment: @AnsonSavage please ask this as a new question.

Comment: This menu is not available in Blender 2.9. Could you make an update to your answer please?