# How can I change the shape for the emission of fire?

Tags: fire

I created a fire on the base of a circle. How can I change the shape of the base where i emitted the fire? Every time that I do the fire does not emit on top of the additional pieces that I extrude from the circle.

Comment: Please make an effort to describe your issue as part of the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I control where smoke and fire are emitted from?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/how-can-i-control-where-smoke-and-fire-are-emitted-from/23247#23247)