# See smoke emitter texture in viewport

Tags: texturing, smoke-simulation

In 2.8+, how can I see a smoke emitter's texture in the viewport, so I have visual reference for the emitting locations?

- Add > Mesh > Plane
- Object > Quick Effects > Quick Smoke
- set up a noise texture in Texture Properties
- select plane
- enable PhysicsProperties > Texture to control the emitting via a texture
- select the noise texture in PhysicsProperties > Texture > Texture

... now the smoke emission is being controlled by the smoke texture. But how can I see this noise texture in the viewport so I have quick visual feedback?

And, along the same lines: how can I set this noise texture as eg the diffuse texture of the emitting object? Ideally I would be referencing the same noise texture in both the smoke emitter, and the smoke emitters shader.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Related: [How can I control where smoke and fire are emitted from?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/how-can-i-control-where-smoke-and-fire-are-emitted-from/23247#23247)

Comment: Thx, cegaton! Although it doesn't help in my case, since I want to use procedural and animated textures to control the emission... which is working, although I have to adjust it blindly.